# How to read file from assets in test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Hi I have problem with reading file from assets. Every time I get NullPointerException. 
I use Roboletric and I have *onBoard.json* in assets folder (*main/assets/onBoard.json* and *testAndroid/assets/onBoard.json*). This is my test class with basic test to open file.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class JsonUtilsTest extends Instrumentation {

@Test
public void readAssetsFileInAndroidTestContextTest() throws IOException {

    ShadowApplication application = ShadowApplication.getInstance();
    assertNotNull(application);
    InputStream input = application.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("onBoard.json");
    assertNotNull(input);
}


@Test
public void strawberryTest() throws Exception {
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("onBoard.json");

}

@Test
public void shouldGetJSONFromAssetTest() throws Exception{
    assertNotNull(RuntimeEnvironment.application); //Getting the application context
    InputStream input = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getAssets().open("onBoard.json");// the file name in asset folder
    assertNotNull(input);
}
}
```

and log message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.open(ShadowAssetManager.java:179)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java)
...
```

All this method return NullPointerException! Here is nullPointer `InputStream`.
Can you give me some advice? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: ***assert** folder* ?????

Comment: Sorry I mean `assets`

Comment: Any updates on this? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to read file from assets :

```
private String readTxt() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
        AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = mngr.open("Your file name.json");

        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e(TAG, byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```